# How to give priority to auto-mount on boot in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: mount, filesystem, ntfs, drive

One of those things that I like in Ubuntu 12.10, is that for some reason my ntfs partition is automatically mounted on boot, without having to use some application like ntfs-config.

However, it's not mounted "when I need", because (for example), I have a symbolic link of my Dropbox folder (which is originally placed in that ntfs partition). Therefore, when I login, the Dropbox is started first than the ntfs filesystem is mounted, and I find that error that the Dropbox folder is not found. If I exit dropbox and start again, it works fine then (because the filesystem is mounted by then).

How can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. Ubuntu loads applications in alphabetical order, so changing the name in Startup will solve your problem.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Changing the name of what to what? The auto-mount is not an application, therefore is not in startup applications.